# Homeomorphism inducing auto-homeomorphism on function space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Suppose that $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are complete metric spaces and let $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a homeomorphism.  Let $C(Z,Z)$ be the set of continuous functions from $Z$ to itself (where Z is a standing for either $X$ or for $Y$) and endow it with the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology).

Define the *induced* map between function spaces by
\begin{align}
\Phi:&C(X,X)\rightarrow C(Y,Y)\\
& f\mapsto \phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}.
\end{align}

Is $\Phi$ then also a homeomorphism?

**Update: Tentative Argument**

Since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, then:

- $K$ is compact in $X$ if and only if $\phi(K)$ is compact in $Y$,
- $\tilde{K}$ is compact in $Y$ if and only if $\phi^{-1}(\tilde{K})$ is compact in $X$,
- $U$ is open in $X$ if and only if $\phi(U)$ is open in $Y$,
- $\tilde{U}$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $\phi^{-1}(\tilde{U})$ is open in $X$,
- $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are bijections so they preserve inclusions of sets,

Therefore, for every $f\in C(X,X)$ such that $f(K)\subseteq U$, where $K,U$ are as above, we have that
$
f(K)\subseteq U 
$
if and only if there is a compact of the form $\tilde{K}=\phi^{-1}(K)\subseteq Y$ such that
$$
f\circ \phi^{-1}(K)\subseteq U
\Leftrightarrow
\phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}(K)\subseteq \phi(U),
$$
and by the above remarks every open subset $V$ of $Y$ can be written in the form $\phi(U)$ for some open subset $U$ of $X$.

Therefore, there is a bijections between the subases of the compact-open topologies; whence $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: It seems that you are allowing $D(f,g)$ to be infinite; is that the intent? Also, does the symbol $\triangleq$ denote anything other than $=$?

Comment: Hello Lee, I made the clarification; I rather not assume that X (or so Y) is compact, so I will restate it with the compact-open topology.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: For an embedding $\phi$ with $\phi(X) \ne Y$ the map $\Phi$ is not well-defined.

Comment: I just realized this also, and have made the modification.

Comment: But then $\Phi$ maps to $C(\phi(X),Y)$. Moreover, your  function spaces have the compact-open topology which is in general not metrizable. If you want that, you must assume that $X$ is compact.

Comment: I recommend to omit the cas of a bi-Lipschitz embedding. For a non-compact $X$ you will not find a metric on your functons spaces.which induces the compact-open topology.

Comment: I'll take the advice, but I'm not looking for a metric to generate the topology, just wondering if the map is continuous on the compact-open topology (with its general definition).

Comment: For the compact case where $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, it should be straightforward to follow the definitions and see that $\Phi$ induces a bijection between the set of sub-basis elements of the compact-open topology on $X$ and the set of sub-basis elements of the compact open topology on $Y$.

Comment: True, but it really isn't clear to me in the general case.

Comment: My comments concerning bi-Lipschitz were motivated by the fact that this concept is only defined for maps between metric spaces. Thus, without metrics on function sapces it does not make sense.

Comment: BTW, it's waaay too easy to confuse $\Phi$ with $\phi$. In the future I advice using some easier to distinguish symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true with any assumptions on $X,Y$. Let us write $Y^X$ for the set of continuous functions $f : X \to Y$ which is endowed with the compact-open topology. This topology depends on the interpretation of "compact". If we understand "compact" to include "Hausdorff", then the resulting compact-open topology is in general coarser than that based on not necessarily Hausdorff compact subsets $K \subset X$. However, if $X$ is Hausdorff, both variants agree.

Given maps $u : Y \to Z, v : T \to X$, it is well-known (and easy to verify) that
$$u_* : Y^X \to Z^X, g_*(f) = u  \circ f$$
is continuous and
$$v^* : Y^X \to Y^T, v^*(f) = f \circ v$$
is continuous *provided* images $v(C)$ of compact $C \subset T$ are compact in the given interpretation of "compact". Thus, in the interpretation not including Hausdorff it is always true, but in the other interpretation it may fail. Anyway, if $v$ is a homeomorphism, then it is true also in the second case.

Now let $\phi : X \to Y$ be a homeomorphism. Then $\phi_* : X^X \to Y^X$ and $(\phi^{-1})_* : Y^X \to X^X$ are inverse homeomorphism since $(\phi^{-1})_*  \circ \phi_* = id$ and $\phi_* \circ (\phi^{-1})_*  = id$. Similarly $(\phi^{-1})^* : Y^X \to Y^Y$ is a homeomorphism. This shows that $\Phi = (\phi^{-1})^* \circ \phi_*$ is a homeomorphism.

Remark: As observed by freakish, we know that  $\Phi = (\phi^{-1})^* \circ \phi_*$ is continuous. Similarly $\Psi = \phi^* \circ (\phi^{-1})_*$ is continuous and obviously $\Psi \circ \Phi = id$ and $\Phi \circ \Psi = id$.

Comment: I don't think you need any assumptions on spaces. If big $\Phi$ is continuous (which seems to be true regardless of what $X,Y$ are?) then it has continuous inverse in the form of $g\mapsto \phi^{-1}\circ g\circ \phi$, right?

Comment: @freakish You are right, I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for any topological spaces $X,Y$. Regardless of what $X,Y$ and homeomorphism $\phi:X\to Y$ are what you've shown is that

$$\Phi_{\phi, X,Y}:C(X,X)\to C(Y,Y)$$
$$\Phi_{\phi, X,Y}(f)=\phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}$$

is continuous. All you have to realize now is that the inverse of $\Phi_{\phi, X,Y}$ is $\Phi_{\phi^{-1}, Y,X}$ which is also continuous by the arbitrary choice of $X,Y$ and $\phi$.